# CSV Writer Issue in Python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

My code is clearly messed up but several tries have led me nowhere. I created a custom dialect as such...

```
def wereofftoseesv(start_id, end_id):
    with open('nba_2015_16_pbp.csv', "w") as f:
        csv.register_dialect('scraper', delimiter="[", lineterminator = '', escapechar='', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='scraper')
        writer.writerows(["gameid", "time_remaining", "entry", "score", "team", "line", "attendance + capacity", "refs"])
        writer.writerows(list_cleaner(start_id, end_id))
```

I thought what this meant is that every time the CSV writer saw a "[" in my code, is would send the output that follows into a new cell.

The final code that I want to send to the CSV looks as such...

```
[[400827889], [([48, 0], 'Timofey Mozgov vs. Pau Gasol (Derrick Rose gains possession)', '0 - 0', 'CHI')], ['CHI -1.5'], ['Attendance: 21,957', 'Capacity: 20,917'], ['Mark Ayotte, Scott Foster, Ben Taylor'], [400827889], [([47, 34],
```

And I would like a new line with all those smaller lists and strings split every time you see the long number "400827889".

At current, my variable names (line 5) are showing up as follows:

```
g[a[m[e[i[d]     t[i[m[e[_[r[e[m[a[i[n[i[n[g]    e[n[t[r[y]  s[c[o[r[e]  t[e[a[m]    l[i[n[e]    a[t[t[e[n[d[a[n[c[e[" "[+[" "[c[a[p[a[c[i[t[y]  r[e[f[s]
```

And my CSV outputs, with "//" being a post-facto addition by me to represent "new cell", are as follows:

```
 "[400827888]"["[([48 //  0] //  'Andre Drummond vs. Al Horford (Ersan Ilyasova gains possession)'//  '0 - 0' //  'ATL')]"["['ATL -6.5']"["['Attendance: 19 // 187' //  'Capacity: 18 // 729']"["['Eli Roe //  Zach Zarba //  Michael Smith']"["[400827888]"["[([47..."
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: You'll notice that for the output, the first list of lists "[[400827889]..." is never resolved. That's because each one of those outside lists represents one game. I'm hoping to just have every all games in a single CSV output, each line being a single line in each game.

Answer (score 1):

So, per [pythons documentation on csv here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), the delimiter is a single character that separates data fields. First thing you want to do is to change `delimiter="[",` to `delimiter=",",`. Then change  `writer.writerows` in line 5 to `write.writerow`.

You should also have `lineterminator = ''` be something other than an empty string.

To be perfectly honest I'm not sure if a csv is your best option for handling your data. As it is it looks like you have a lot of repeating data - you don't need the line, refs, attendance, etc for every line of data.

Comment: That is a possibility -- just reproducing the non-repeating data in a CSV and the other supplemental repeating stuff elsewhere. Any suggestions for other options besides CSV? Thanks for your help

Comment: This may be overkill but you could use a relational database. Python has a pretty good [sqlite api.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)